# App icon showing before Splash screen image on Mobile App

Tags: ios, codenameone

I recently starting seeing the icon selected for the App display before the image selected for Mobile App. Please advise if any one notice similar thing with latest iOS update and how to avoid displaying the icon.

Thanks

Comment: Did you see it stretched out to the whole screen? If so, don't worry: this is a known iOS bug where the icon scale animation freezes.

Comment: it is not streched but I dont want to see the icon because I have configured different image to show on splash screen. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

This was discussed [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/no-more-ios-screenshots.html) it's an old feature which is now on by default. You should customize the XIB to get a different look for the splash screen. We might add additional default configurations in the future based on RFE's.

Comment: Shai, no even with build hint I see the icon but after the splash screen logo, icon will appear and go away. please advise if anything has been changed? Thanks

Comment: Try setting `ios.multitasking=false` as well to disable this completely

Comment: Thank You Shai. Question, Does this has any impact on any other action for Mobile App. As this a stopping the ios to do any multitasking

Comment: It will stop the side/by side type of multi-tasking functionality. It won't stop moving between apps and has nothing to do with background behavior.

Comment: Shai, I have added build hints : ios.multitasking = false and ios.generateSplashScreens = true still I see the icon display after the splash screen. Please advise what else can be done? Thanks

Comment: I'll have to look into that

Comment: Sure can you please let me know.

Comment: I suggest filing an issue on this

Comment: I've the same issue in iOS devices. The issue was not there before.

Comment: Shai, As this is on build server and I have to release the build as soon as possible, how long will it take to fix this issue.

Comment: Hopefully next week